# Не получается подсчитать конечные суммы в запросе Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Такая задача!
Имеются данные о заработке каждого участника и количестве проведенных ими работ:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+-------+
|  Группа  |  Участник  | Заработок | Работ |
+----------+------------+-----------+-------+
| Группа 1 | Участник 1 |       200 |     4 |
| Группа 1 | Участник 2 |       200 |     6 |
| Группа 1 | Участник 3 |       400 |     1 |
| Группа 1 | Участник 4 |       400 |     5 |
| Группа 2 | Участник 5 |       300 |     1 |
| Группа 2 | Участник 6 |       400 |     3 |
| Группа 2 | Участник 7 |       400 |     6 |
| Группа 3 | Участник 6 |       300 |     2 |
| Группа 3 | Участник 8 |       300 |     4 |
| Группа 3 | Участник 9 |       300 |     6 |
+----------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

Рассчитываю бонус (процент) от заработка таким образом, если в группе в среднем было проведено 4 и более работы, то в группе участников всем даю 20% от заработка; Помимо этого, даю 10% участнику, который провел больше всего работ из всей организации (даю всем 10% от заработка, если таких участников несколько)

Нужно получить данные в таком виде и сделать это через grоuрing sеts без объединения результатов нескольких инструкций sеlеct:

```
+----------+------------+-------+---------+
|  Группа  |  Участник  | Работ | Процент |
+----------+------------+-------+---------+
|          |            |    38 |     510 |
| Группа 1 | Участник 2 |     6 |      60 |
| Группа 2 | Участник 7 |     6 |      40 |
| Группа 3 | Участник 9 |     6 |      90 |
| Группа 1 |            |    16 |     260 |
| Группа 1 | Участник 1 |     4 |      40 |
| Группа 1 | Участник 2 |     6 |      60 |
| Группа 1 | Участник 3 |     1 |      80 |
| Группа 1 | Участник 4 |     5 |      80 |
| Группа 2 |            |    10 |      40 |
| Группа 2 | Участник 5 |     1 |       0 |
| Группа 2 | Участник 6 |     3 |       0 |
| Группа 2 | Участник 7 |     6 |      40 |
| Группа 3 |            |    14 |     210 |
| Группа 3 | Участник 6 |     2 |      60 |
| Группа 3 | Участник 8 |     4 |      60 |
| Группа 3 | Участник 9 |     6 |      90 |
+----------+------------+-------+---------+
```

Таблица такая:

```sql
create table Tab (Группа varchar2(100), Участник varchar2(100), Заработок number, Работ number);

delete Tab;
insert into Tab (Группа, Участник, Заработок, Работ) values ('Группа 1','Участник 1',200,4);
insert into Tab (Группа, Участник, Заработок, Работ) values ('Группа 1','Участник 2',200,6);
insert into Tab (Группа, Участник, Заработок, Работ) values ('Группа 1','Участник 3',400,1);
insert into Tab (Группа, Участник, Заработок, Работ) values ('Группа 1','Участник 4',400,5);
insert into Tab (Группа, Участник, Заработок, Работ) values ('Группа 2','Участник 5',300,1); 
insert into Tab (Группа, Участник, Заработок, Работ) values ('Группа 2','Участник 6',400,3);
insert into Tab (Группа, Участник, Заработок, Работ) values ('Группа 2','Участник 7',400,6);
insert into Tab (Группа, Участник, Заработок, Работ) values ('Группа 3','Участник 6',300,2); 
insert into Tab (Группа, Участник, Заработок, Работ) values ('Группа 3','Участник 8',300,4); 
insert into Tab (Группа, Участник, Заработок, Работ) values ('Группа 3','Участник 9',300,6);

commit;
```

Данным запросом я получаю всё, в том числе 3-х лидеров по выполнению наибольшего количества работ и которые же получили 10% от заработка.

Почти желаемый результат получаю таким запросом, но есть косяк:

```sql
select
Группа5 Группа,
Участник2 Участник,
Работ2 Работы,
(case when grp1 = 1 and grp2 = 1 then sum(Заработок2+Заработок3) over (order by Группа2, grp1)
 when grp1 = 1 and grp2 = 0 then sum(Заработок2+Заработок3) over (partition by Группа2 order by Группа2, grp1) else Заработок2+Заработок3 end) Суммы
from (
select
Группа1 Группа2,
(case when grp1 = 0 and grp2 = 1 and max(Работ1) over (partition by Группа1, grp1 order by grp1)=Работ1 then (select Группа from Tab where Участник = Участник1) else Группа1 end) Группа5,
Участник1 Участник2,
Работ1 Работ2,
(case when grp1 = 0 and avg(Работ1) over (partition by Группа1, grp1 order by grp1)>=4 then (Заработок1*0.2) else 0 end) Заработок2,
(case when grp1 = 0 and max(Работ1) over (partition by Группа1, grp1 order by grp1)=Работ1 then (Заработок1*0.1) else 0 end) Заработок3,
grp1,
grp2
from (
select
Группа Группа1,
Участник Участник1,
sum(Работ) Работ1,
sum(Заработок) Заработок1,
grouping(Участник) grp1,
grouping(Группа) grp2
from Tab
group by grouping sets ((null), (Группа), (Участник), (Группа, Участник))
)
order by Группа1, Участник1
)
where (Группа5 is not null or Участник2 is null)
order by  grp2 desc, Группа2 asc, grp1 desc, Участник2 asc
```

Этим запросом я в grоuрing sеts дополнительно анализирую (Участник), что позволяет мне обрабатывать записи с grоuрing(Группа)=1 и grоuрing(Участник)=0 для определения лидеров в организации. Но при этом у меня начинает неверно подсчитываться общая сумма процента и процент лидера "Участник 7" (см. результат в запросе №2).

Как мне получить лидеров в запросе с корректными суммами процентов? (Таблица 2, Строки 2,3,4)

Answer (score 0):

Я не стал разбираться, что именно вы намудрили в своей выборке. Но если данные в таблице нормализованны:

```
WITH поУчастнику AS (SELECT t.участник FROM tab t 
                      GROUP BY t.участник 
                     HAVING SUM(t.работ) = 
                                 (SELECT MAX(SUM(t.работ)) 
                                    FROM tab t GROUP BY t.участник)),
     поГруппе    AS (SELECT t.группа FROM tab t
                      GROUP BY t.группа
                     HAVING SUM(t.работ)/COUNT(t.участник) >= 4)
SELECT группа, участник, SUM(работ) работ, SUM(процент) процент 
  FROM (
          SELECT t.группа
               , t.участник
               , t.работ
               , DECODE(поУчастнику.участник, NULL, 0, 10) 
                   + DECODE(поГруппе.группа, NULL, 0, 20) процент
            FROM tab t
                 LEFT JOIN поУчастнику ON поУчастнику.участник = t.участник
                 LEFT JOIN поГруппе    ON поГруппе.группа      = t.группа
       )
  GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((группа), (группа,участник), ())
ORDER BY 1 NULLS FIRST, 2 NULLS FIRST;
```

Результат Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production:

```
ГРУППА    УЧАСТНИК     РАБОТ   ПРОЦЕНТ
--------- ---------- ------- ---------
                          38       170
Группа 1                  16        90
Группа 1  Участник 1       4        20
Группа 1  Участник 2       6        30
Группа 1  Участник 3       1        20
Группа 1  Участник 4       5        20
Группа 2                  10        10
Группа 2  Участник 5       1        0
Группа 2  Участник 6       3        0
Группа 2  Участник 7       6        10
Группа 3                  12        70
Группа 3  Участник 6       2        20
Группа 3  Участник 8       4        20
Группа 3  Участник 9       6        30
```

Добавьте в **GROUPING SETS** то что вам необходимо.